# How to construct continuous functions on arbitrary topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Constructing continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ (with the euclidean topology) is easy: there is a quite large collection of elementary functions, and we can get even more by composing/adding/multiplying them.

Given a function between arbitrary topological spaces, $f: (X,\tau) \to (Y,\sigma)$, it is easy to check whether $f$ is continuous: $f$ is continuous if and only if $\tau$ contains the set $$H=\{f^{-1}(U) | U\in \sigma\}$$

What I don't understand is how to go in the other direction: given two topological spaces, how do you construct functions that you can expect to be continuous? Is there some general intuition for constructing continuous functions in a general setting?

(Of course, you can always choose a function that is constant on the connected components of $X$, but I want to do better)

Comment: well if one space has the discrete topology (the source) you won't be able to. Without further assumptions, only constants are guaranteed.

Comment: I'm not asking for a full description of all continuous functions between two arbitrary topological spaces, rather whether there's any general intuition on how to make a function that's continuous, depending on how fine $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are relative to each other